# git merge doesn't update .gitignore

Tags: git, merge, gitignore

I have a problem with updating the .gitignore file across multiple branches. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

The steps I took are the following:

- git checkout master
- add 2 lines to the pre-existing file .gitignore
- git commit
- git push
- git checkout develop
- git merge master
- "Already up to date"

I went back to master - where my 2 lines are still present in .gitignore -, tried to commit again ("No changes detected"), tried to push again ("Nothing to push"), checked out develop again and merged master again ("Already up to date").

So now my .gitignore file differs on my 2 branches and there seems to be no way to get the change from master into develop.

(Of course I could manually add the same 2 lines I added in master, in develop, but that doesn't solve the nature of the problem.)

Comment: Did you do a `git commit -a`? Did you add `.gitignore` before the first commit?

Comment: I didn't have to, .gitignore was already there. It's an old file.

Comment: You still have to do a git add .ignore as the file will not automatically be included for commit unless specifically added. When you modify the file and do a git status, you'll see it's highlighted in red and listed under "Changes not staged for commit:". When you do a git add it will be highlighted in green and listed under "Changes to be committed:".

Comment: I confirm. Without `git add`, any modification to a file would be ignored (even a "pre-existing" file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a git add before your commit. Let me elaborate, you say you do the following:

1. git checkout master
2. add 2 lines to the pre-existing file .gitignore
3. git commit
   etc.

I would have expected:

1. git checkout master
2. add 2 lines to the pre-existing file .gitignore
3. git add .gitignore
4. git commit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't get it; why would I have to do 'git add' if it's only modified, not new?

Comment: Because files are not staged for commit unless you do a git add. So say you changed 10 files but only wanted to include one in your commit, you'd just add that one file, then it would be staged for commit.

Comment: I did it again and now it worked, but I still don't get what the difference is between this files and the thousands of other files I've edited, committed and pushed. Maybe it's important to say that I committed and pushed from my IDE; my IDE probably does the 'git add' for me.

Comment: In other words: I did what I always do. Edit a file; commit using PHPStorm; push; checkout different branch; merge. It only didn't work with this specific file. I was however able to merge the other files I altered in the same commit.

Comment: @EduardLuca amended answer based on your feedback.